# Kotlin & Generic delegates, how to switch between subclasses

Tags: generics, kotlin, delegates

I am facing a problem and I'd like your feedbacks on this one, especially on how to properly handle the following case:

I have an abstract class that defines a delegate:

```
abstract class Delegate<T: Any> {
    abstract fun bindData(item: T?)
}
```

And then I have 2 implementations of this delegate:

```
class DelegateForObjectA: Delegate<A>() {
    var data: A? = null

    override fun bindData(item: A?){
        data = item
    }
}

class DelegateForObjectB: Delegate<B>() {
    var data: B? = null

    override fun bindData(item: B?) {
        data = item
    }
}
```

I want to be able to switch between these 2 delegates on the fly, meaning that in my activity I have:

```
lateinit var delegate: ActionButtonsViewDelegate<*>
private var delegateA by lazy { DelegateForObjectA() }
private var delegateB by lazy { DelegateForObjectB() }

init {
    delegate = delegateA
}
```

And then later:

```
fun SwitchDelegateAndBindData(item: Any?) {
    if (item is B) {
        delegate = delegateB
    } else {
        delegate = delegateA
    }

    delegate.bindData(item)
}
```

I've tried achieving this with in/out but no success! How can i declare my delegate property to accept both delegates without having conflict on the type?

Comment: Are `A` and `B` actual class names here, or parameters?  If they're actual class names, then you don't need to parameterise your subclasses with them: `DelegateForObjectA : Delegate<A>`, not `DelegateForObjectA<A> : Delegate<A>`.  (Not sure if this affects the main issue.)

Comment: hm you're right it's a type! the code is DelegateForObjectA : Delegate<A>

Comment: What error does it show?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make it work, although i'm not sure exactly why it works and if it really suits your needs ^^'

```
/**
 * You can edit, run, and share this code. 
 * play.kotlinlang.org 
 */

fun main() {
    val a = A()
    val b = B()
    val test = Test()

    test.switchDelegate(a)
    test.switchDelegate(b)
    test.switchDelegate(a)
}

class Test {
    var delegate: Delegate<*>
    private val delegateA by lazy { DelegateForObjectA() }
    private val delegateB by lazy { DelegateForObjectB() }

    init {
        delegate = delegateA
    }

    fun switchDelegate(item: Any) {
        if (item is B) {
            delegate = delegateB
        } else {
            delegate = delegateA
        }
        delegate.bindData( item )
    }
}

abstract class Delegate<T> {
    abstract fun <T:Any> bindData(item : T)
}

class A {}

class B {}

class DelegateForObjectA: Delegate<A>() {
    override fun <A:Any> bindData(item: A){
        println( "Binding A" )
    }
}

class DelegateForObjectB: Delegate<B>() {
    override fun <B:Any> bindData(item: B) {
        println( "Binding B" )
    }
}
```